# how to implement generic array list copy constructor?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyStack<T> {

private ArrayList<T> stack;

    // Copy constructor
    public MyStack(MyStack<T> s) {

        // i know its wrong
        for(int i = 0; i < stack.size(); i++) {
           this.stack.get(i) = s.stack.get(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `get()` and `set()` are opposites.

Comment: the class is generic MyStack<T> as well as ArrayList<T> idk y its not showing it

Comment: Just for future reference @user2877264 - this code won't successfully compile, because a retrieval can't be used as an assignment target, only a variable can.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
// Copy constructor
public MyStack(MyStack<T> s) {
    this.stack = new ArrayList<T>(s.stack);    
}
```

Comment: but its private ArrayList<T> stack; i need to copy all the elements

Comment: This will copy all the reference to elements in the stack.  What is your doubt? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: i did it this way  this.stack = new ArrayList<T>(); 
  
  for(int i = 0; i < stack.size(); i++) {
         this.stack.add(s.stack.get(i));
     }

Comment: is it the same thing ?

Comment: @user2877264 It is basically the same, just longer.  You can look at the Javadoc or code for the constructor to see for yourself.

Comment: how would u properly test this method ?

Comment: @user2877264 That depends on how it is going to be used and why you are taking a copy.  Is a shallow copy ok or will the value be changed, in which case you might need a deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to debug at all? An obvious suggestion would be to make sure that you're referencing the correct stack.

Comment: Possibly a comment rather than an answer, but I doubt it compiles so you can't debug it.

Comment: This should have been a comment. My mistake